# Display only single line at a time, in a Multiline Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have tried android:singleLine, maxLines, lineSpacing attributes but my EditText always displays a part of next line. How can I force it to display a single line at a time?

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/formulaView"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/visible_cursor"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Show your xml layout code.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Yes, added.

Comment: set EditText height to wrap_content

Comment: Do you want to cut the lines except the first one or fit multiple lines onto a single line?

Comment: @AmanGrover When i set it to wrap_content, edittext expands on new line. To prevent expanding, i set maxLines = 1. Even then, the second line is visible.

Comment: @BurakCakir I want the edittext to display only single line, aligned center_vertically, yet when user scrolls show other lines.

Comment: Don't use a multiline edit text.  There's no support for only showing a single line in one.

Comment: @Siva set  android:layout_height="wrap_content" and android:singleLine="true" at the same time

Comment: @GabeSechan No.. Check out Microsoft Excel android app. They have done it somehow.

Comment: @BurakCakir That removes my most needed multi line feature altogether.

Comment: @Siva I highly doubt excel isn't using a totally custom view.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan.. You think they developed an EditText From scratch without extending TextView?

Comment: Given all the other stiff they need it to do? Yes, I think it's likely. Especially as text view is open source, they could crack it open and make deep customization to it. I've done that to a few android widgets over the last decade.

Comment: @GabeSachen So, I'm left with the same option i guess. I Grepcoded TextView.. Looks doable but I have no idea where to start. Could you point me where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Instead use:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Code:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/formulaView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="=SUM(android,Hello,How,Are,You) GoodMorining"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Hope this will help.

*Have a great day ahead.*